# propositions in modern logic?

Tags: logic

What s the story of proposition and asserting it in modern logic? I am aware of the story, but the idea of replacing proposition with asserting doesn't seem to me accurate, what do you? Was it replacement?

Comment: I would assume Frege was still with assertion, he had an assertion sign after all

Comment: In a sense this is not wrong. The short story could be interpreted as over the years logic as a field of study of the subjective normative nature since ancient morphed to a fundamental field of the objective declarative nature supposed to be foundation of all sciences and mathematics...

Comment: See also the post ["Interpretation" versus "judgement" versus "assertion"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949646/interpretation-versus-judgement-versus-assertion).

Answer (score 6):

It was Frege who introduced the assertion stroke and distinguished it from the content stroke. I shall use |- for former and - for the latter. The idea is to distinguish the content of an expression from the judgment that what is expressed is true. So, for example, writing

```
- Alice is tall
```

merely asks the reader to entertain the thought of Alice being tall, while

```
|- Alice is tall
```

*asserts* that Alice is tall. In the latter case, if Alice is not tall then the person who uttered the sentence has made an error. The content identifies a potential assertion, and the judgment makes the assertion.

The distinction was important for Frege, because we can understand the correctness of an argument without asserting anything. Consider the argument, "Alice is tall or Mary is tall; Mary is not tall; therefore, Alice is tall". The natural way to understand someone who utters this is that they are asserting the premises to be true, and drawing the inference that the conclusion is also true. But arguments may be recognised as safe, or as conforming to safe rules, even when the premises and conclusion are understood hypothetically and not asserted. Today we would prefer to say that this argument is valid, even if it is not sound.

In modern usage, I would say that it is Frege's 'content' that has morphed into the modern concept of proposition, while Frege's 'assertion' has become part of speech act theory. An assertion is a performative act.

The issue is somewhat complicated by the fact that there is no consensus among philosophers over what a proposition is. David Lewis observed that the different ways in which philosophers use the term are so diverse as to be incompatible. It is used in all of the following ways:

- The primary bearer of truth.
- A meaningful declarative or descriptive sentence.
- A declarative or descriptive sentence with the indexicals and references unambiguously resolved.
- The semantic content of a meaningful declarative or descriptive sentence.
- The language-independent meaning of a declarative or descriptive sentence.
- The object of propositional attitudes, i.e. the things that stand in place of p in expressions like "believes that p", "hopes that p", "fears that p", etc.
- The object of that-clauses, i.e. the things that stand in place of p in expressions like "the fact that p", "the possibility that p", etc.

Comment: This resembles the use of |= tau with the empty set on the LHS in Enderton to mean that tau is a tautology.

Comment: I don't think it is correct to conflate Frege's judgment stroke with the turnstile or double turnstile. For Frege, |- A asserts that A is true, not that it is tautologous. There are quite a few other differences.

Comment: Wait, but what was a Frege's proposition then? He clearly had in mind a distinction between judgement/assertion and proposition? His "content" was his proposition. Because in his On Sense and Reference, his proposition is the thought content of a sentence, and its referent is the sentence's truth value. Now, how can you say that proposition today mean something like a sharable content of a sentence? Because, proposition today replaced assertion, and assertion is not the content?!

Comment: Where is your reference on Lewis's view?

Comment: I'm saying that Frege's content, or proposition, has morphed into the modern proposition. A proposition may be true or false, just as for Frege the reference of a proposition is a truth value. An assertion is something quite different: a speech act that is performed.

Comment: David Lewis, On The Plurality of Worlds, pp.54-55. "The conception we associate with the word 'proposition' may be something of a jumble of conflicting desiderata. Part of the idea is that propositions are supposed to be true or false simpliciter [...] a proposition is not supposed to be true on one interpretation but false on another [...] true for me but false for you. But another part of the idea is that propositions are supposed to be objects of thought. They are supposed to be capable of giving the content of what we know, believe and desire ...

Comment: If propositions, rightly so called, must be true or false relative to worlds and nothing else, then you had better say that the objects of at least some thoughts turn out not to be propositions. Whereas if you insist that propositions, rightly so called, are the things that serve as objects of all thought, then you had better admit that some propositions are egocentric."

Comment: The Sense and Reference paper says only a little about judgments and assertions. The main reference for that is the Begriffsschrift.

Comment: Perhaps 'potential' might be better than 'hypothetical'. "That Alice is tall" is just an item of propositional content. It may be asserted as "Alice is tall" or it may not.

Answer (score 2):

The SEP article on propositions [("briefly") goes over the history of the concept](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/#history):

> It is difficult to find in the writings of Plato or Aristotle a clear endorsement of propositions in our sense. ... Arguably, the first employment in the western philosophical tradition of the notion of proposition, in roughly our sense, is found in the writings of the Stoics. ... The notion of a proposition can also be found in the works of Medieval philosophers, including especially Abelard (1079–1142) and his followers, but also among later scholastic philosophers in England, including Adam Wodeham (d. 1358) and Walter Burleigh (1275–1344). ... When we turn to the early modern period, it is not easy to find, at least in the writings of major philosophers, an unabashed assertion of the reality of propositions. Unsurprisingly, one looks in vain in the writings of the British empiricists. As for Descartes, particular acts of judgments serve as the primary bearers of truth-value (although there is considerable debate about the status of his eternal truths). Leibniz’s *cogitato possibilis* have some of the characteristics of propositions. ... Propositionalists were by no means rare in the 19th century, Gottlob Frege being the best known example. The Czech philosopher and mathematician Bernard Bolzano also deserves special mention. ... Arguably, the three figures whose work has most shaped the framework for contemporary Anglophone work on propositions are Gottlob Frege, G.E. Moore, and Bertrand Russell.

They bring up Moore and Russell's doubts about propositionalism too, though. Now, a [plausible argument for propositionalism, as against sententialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/#PropVersSent), involves Tarski's schematism for truth (the argument is not extracted from a debate about propositionalism directly, but is relevant to such a debate):

> [Consider] (12) *Snow is white* is true if and only if snow is white.

> Now, does ‘*snow is white*’ in (12) refer to a sentence or a proposition? If, on the one hand, we take (12) to be about a sentence, then, assuming (12) can be interpreted as making a necessary claim, it is false. On the face of it, after all, it takes a lot more than snow’s being white for it to be the case that ‘snow is white’ is true. In order for ‘snow is white’ to be true, it must be the case not only that snow is white, it must, in addition, be the case that ‘snow is white’ *means that* snow is white. But this is a fact about language that (12) ignores. On the other hand, suppose we take ‘*snow is white*’ in (12) to denote the proposition that snow is white. Then the approach looks to be trivial, since the proposition that snow is white is defined as being the one that is true just in case snow is white.

One can use interpreted sentences to get Tarski's biconditional to go through, but it seems easier to get the necessity of the biconditional on a propositionalist basis. (Or perhaps there's a way to detach necessity from biconditions, I don't know. The argument, here, has always been somewhat counterintuitive for me, despite a professor explaining it to me personally many, many years ago.) So I wouldn't say that propositionalism at some point dominated sententialism, on account of musings about Tarski's biconditional, except to say that in my own case, this dominance occurred upon reflection upon those musings.